# How to have view models implement test services, while dagger 2 setup extends DaggerApplication, and uses a Component.Builder

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, robolectric

During testing, my view models are still using production services, and I want them to use test services. I'm using robolectric for testing, and still haven't found a solution to my problem.

What I thought would be most promising would be using a viewModelFactory generator in my test fragment, like `ViewModelUtil.createFor(mockedViewModel)` is used in the [GitHubBrowserSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/103dac5015f51e179039c45c0184418c368ee922/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/android/example/github/ui/repo/RepoFragmentTest.kt#L91). But that's not working for me, my test services created in the mocked viewModel will then get replaced by production services when running `startFragment` as shown below.

My main application extends DaggerApplication() and my production component uses a @Component.Builder so I'm not able to specify a module in my building process.

Additionally, I've tried having `TestAppComponent` extend from my `AppComponent` but that doesn't seem to do the trick either.

I've also tried setting a builder as a static object in MyApplication.kt like so:

```
companion object {
    var builder: AndroidInjector.Factory<MyApplication> = 
        DaggerAppComponent.builder()
}

...

override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
    return builder.create(this)
}
```

And in my FragmentTest.kt init doing something like:

```
    private fun init() {
        bagFragment = BagFragment.newInstance()
        MyApplication.builder = DaggerTestAppComponent.builder()

        SupportFragmentTestUtil.startFragment(bagFragment, AppCompatActivity::class.java)
    }
```

But that doesn't work because of a type mismatches. If there was some solution where extending from DaggerApplication() was still a possibility I would be very interested in that.

Here's my setup:

AppComponent.kt

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    AndroidInjectionModule::class,
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
    AppModule::class,
    ActivityModule::class,
    FragmentModule::class,
    ProductionModule::class])
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<MyApplication>{

    @Component.Builder
    abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<MyApplication>()
}
```

ProductionModule.kt

```
@Module
open class ProductionModule {

    @Provides
    fun browseCategoriesViewModel(authenticationService: AuthenticationService): BrowseCategoriesFragment.BrowseCategoriesViewModel{
        return BrowseCategoriesFragment.BrowseCategoriesViewModel(authenticationService)
    }
// Provides multiple things
...
```

ViewModelModule.kt

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factor: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

    /*** Fragments ***/
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(BagFragment.BagViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindBagViewModel(viewModel: BagFragment.BagViewModel): ViewModel
```

MyApplication.kt

```
class MyApplication: DaggerApplication(), HasActivityInjector, HasSupportFragmentInjector {

    @Inject
    lateinit var sharedPreferencesService: SharedPreferencesService

    @Inject
    lateinit var activityInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

    @Inject
    lateinit var supportFragmentInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>

    override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context?) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base)
        MultiDex.install(this)
    }

    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder().create(this)
    }

    override fun activityInjector() = activityInjector

    override fun supportFragmentInjector() = supportFragmentInjector
}
```

The AppModule, FragmentModule, and ActivityModule are set up according to documentation, and haven't given me any issues.

Here is my test setup:

TestAppComponent.kt

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules =[
    AndroidInjectionModule::class,
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
    TestModule::class])
interface TestAppComponent: AndroidInjector<MyApplication>{

    @Component.Builder
    abstract class Builder: AndroidInjector.Builder<MyApplication>()
}
```

TestModule.kt

```
@Module
internal class TestModule {

    @Provides
    fun bagViewModel(dataService: FakeDataService,
                     authenticationService: FakeAuthenticationService,
                     favoritesService: FakeFavoritesService,
                     cartService: FakeCartService): BagFragment.BagViewModel {
        return BagFragment.BagViewModel(dataService, authenticationService, favoritesService, cartService)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun dataService(): FakeDataService = FakeDataService()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun authenticationService(): FakeAuthenticationService = FakeAuthenticationService()

// provides many other things
```

My current test fragment init method looks like this:

```
    private fun init() {
        bagFragment = BagFragment.newInstance()        
        SupportFragmentTestUtil.startFragment(bagFragment, AppCompatActivity::class.java)
    }
```

Last but not least, an example production fragment:

BagFragment.kt

```
    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    lateinit var viewModel: BagViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(BagViewModel::class.java)
    }
```

When I call `SupportFragmentTestUtil.startFragment()` i'm assuming that `AndroidInjection.inject(this)` will replace my fake test module with the production module. I've also tried putting `AndroidInjection.inject(this)` in an `init` method as opposed to `onCreate` but that gives me problems else where and is contrary to documentation. Please help!